# Windows 8 Apps - plist equivalent to hold dictionaries

Tags: microsoft-metro, plist, porting, c++-cx

In iOS plist files are useful resources since you can hold an array or a dictionary inside it and read from the plist file using a code like this:

```
 NSMutableDictionary *myDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] 
                                    initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Is there any structure to have a similar behavior in a Windows 8 App using C++/Cx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for Dictionary data structure you can use:

```
Dictionary<TKey, TValue>
// simple example, dictionary of Uris
Dictionary<string, Uri>
// or advanced example, dictionary of lists of strings
Dictionary<string, List<string>>
```

Or if you're looking for a place where to save application settings, you can use [ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localsettings). Note you can save only primitive types in there and each entry must be smaller than about 4kB.
If You want to preserve larger data in your app, like configuration object or list of favorite items, you have to save them into [ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localfolder.aspx) serialized into Json for instance.

Comment: sorry but I didn't find any documentation on Dictionary. Do you mean Map?

Comment: Here's a basic documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx and tutorial how to use it http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary